# Vista gadget/javascript passing variables question

Tags: javascript, windows-desktop-gadgets

I've been struggling with this and can't find a single tutorial on what seems to be a very simple idea.

I've written to the settings in the settings.html file using:

```
System.Gadget.Settings.writeString("Date1", month + "-" + day + "-" + year);
```

And that seems to have worked. It displays properly in the settings.

Now, in the main file, gadget.html, I want to pull the data out and display it (not in an input tag). What is the complete code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Write it to an xml file and use ajax to read it.
Alternatively, write it to a .js file and import it with a `<script src=...></script>` construct.